# Replace strings in file concurently in golang

Tags: go

I've a huge text file containing some strings to be replaced and i want to do that in a concurrent way so that i'll be able to replace more than one string , here's my current code :

```
        import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        "strings"
        "sync"
    )
    
    
    var fileMutex sync.Mutex
    
   var (
    oldHelloWorld = "hel world"
    newHelloWorld = "hello world"
    oldJohnDoe    = "joh doe"
    newJohnDoe    = "John Doe"
    oldJaneDoe    = "jane doeee"
    newJaneDoe    = "Jane Doe"
    )
    
    var (
        changesHolder = map[string]string{
          oldHelloWorld: newHelloWorld,
          oldJohnDoe: newJohnDoe,
          oldJaneDoe: newJaneDoe,
        }
    )
    
    func doReplace(fileName,newContent string, wg *sync.WaitGroup)  {
    
        fileMutex.Lock()
        defer fileMutex.Unlock()
        defer wg.Done()
        err := ioutil.WriteFile(fileName, []byte(newContent), 0)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    
    func replace(fileName string){
    
        var wg *sync.WaitGroup = new(sync.WaitGroup)
        read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        var newContent = ""
        for key, value := range changesHolder {
            wg.Add(1)
            newContent = strings.Replace(string(read), key, value, -1)
    
            go doReplace(fileName,newContent, wg)
        }
    
        wg.Wait()
    }
    
    func main() {
       replace("myText.txt")
    }
```

But the result is only the last changesHolder element (**oldJaneDoe**) which gets replaced although my text file contains all other occurrences.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because each goroutine is replacing only one of the strings and rewriting the whole file. The last one to write wins. You said the file is really large, but you're reading the whole thing in memory. If the file is large, the gain from concurrency in replacing strings will be negligible. File I/O will dominate. Write a simple algorithm instead.

Comment: You are reading the file and then starting off multiple go routines each of which writes a modified version of the file (in full, overwriting any previous version). I don't think this will benefit from concurrency as written; the following will be simpler and faster: read the file, make all of the replacements, write new contents to file.

Comment: Use strings.Replacer.

Comment: "Concurrency!" is not a magic spell to make all things faster.

Answer (score 0):

`strings.Replace` use StringBuilder, so  it can't concurrent

you can write a byte replace function youself

follow is a example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var (
    changesHolder = map[byte]byte{
        'a': '1',
        'b': '2',
        'c': '3',
    }
)

func Replace(bs []byte, old byte, new byte) {
    for i, b := range bs {
        if b == old {
            bs[i] = new
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    b := []byte("aa bb cc")
    for old, new := range changesHolder {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Replace(b, old, new)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
}
```